# Why my onInit not called?

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

In my application I've included Text-To-Speech.

But i dont know why my onInit is not being called and hence the language didn't change. I can't find any answers that suit my problem here. Any help?

my toast is not showing out also. that's when i know it didnt go into it.

```
public void onInit(int initStatus) {
    //check for successful instantiation
    //Toast.makeText(this, initStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Text To Speech ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text-To-Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I use onItemClickListener because i'm using the gridView with Base Adapter..

onItemClickListener :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Item at pos "+ position +" clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "ItemName : " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(arrImages.get(position)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String words = getResources().getResourceEntryName(arrImages.get(position));

    String word = db.getPronunciation(words);
    speakWords(word);
    //int imageID = adapter.arrImages.get(position);
}
```

speakWords:

```
private void speakWords(String speech) {
    //implement TTS here
    //speak straight away
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

TTS Object :

```
//TTS object
private TextToSpeech myTTS;
//status check code
private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
```

In onCreate :

```
Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

In onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else {
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is onInit from the OnInitListner interface ?

Comment: yesyes i implemented onInitListener.. @Blackbelt

Comment: Show to us the onClicklistener please

Comment: this is shwon in your screen `Toast.makeText(this, "ItemName : " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(arrImages.get(position)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`?

Comment: Btw... I don't see any `onInit(int i);` on this code :D

Comment: @Skizo yesyes.. it shows.. my app working fine but it didnt change the language to US locale.. what do you mean by you dont see onInit?? means i have to call it on my own??

Comment: @Michimcchicken When you want to call onInit?

Comment: @Skizo i thought it automatically call when the user launch my app.. i want it to launch as soon as the app launches..

Comment: @Boss the speech everything is fine.. i change my phone's tts language to korean and it speak like korean.. just that it wasn't suppose to be still in korean.. twas suppose to be changed to Locale.US... after my app launches @@

Comment: Try adding an else case for this `if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)`

Comment: why is my TextToSpeech.Language_AVAILABLE not equals to isLanguageAvailable? D:

Comment: onCreate() {myTTS= new TextToSpeech(this, this);}

Comment: @Ajay i put it at onActivityResult is it wrong? o.o